# Sending all items to textbox from listbox in vb?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, listbox

I add items to a listbox with buttons. I'm trying to send the 'all' items in listbox to textbox with another button.

My problem is that i cannot send all items, it goes one by one.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please show the relevant which reproduces the problem.  Also, please give a detailed example of what is currently happening vs. what you want to happen.  Currently, your question is too vague to give you a good answer.

Comment: I think that something that you may be wanting to use is the `String.Join()` method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx

Comment: http://s13.postimg.org/g4b16de5z/aciklama.jpg @StevenDoggart

Answer (score 1):

To do something like that, you need to loop through all of the items in the list and combine them all into a single string.  Then you can display the formatted string in the text box.  The best way to continuously append to a string is to use the `StringBuilder` class, like this:

```
Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
For Each i As Object In ListBox1.Items
    builder.AppendLine(i.ToString())
Next
TextBox1.Text = builder.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to put all the items in the listbox into the textbox with a newline in between each listboxitem, you could do something like this:

```
textBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToArray());
```

Or you could just insert a different string separator into the first param, such as a comma, if you want the string to be one line.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx

HTH